# Can I reuse the express.js error view?

Tags: express

When express can't find a view it errors out and (in debug mode) renders a nice looking page. Is there a convenient way to re-use that view for my own error messages?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to reuse the view but you can use the error.stack to render the stack trace.

I have something like this:

```
app.all( '*', function(req, res){
  var code = 404;
  res.local('error', { type: 'http', code: code });
  res.local('code', code );
  res.render('errors/index', { status: code } );
});

app.error(function(err, req, res, next){

  var code;

  if( err.type === 'http' ){
    code = err.error;
  } 
  else {
    code = 500;
  };

  if(err){
    res.local('stack', err.stack || JSON.stringify(err, null, 2) );
  };

  res.local('code', code );
  res.render('errors/index', { status: code } );

});
```

If I need to manually set like a 404 I do the following in my views:

```
next( {type:'http', error: 404} );
```

That's where there is a type check in my views.

Comment: Yes, it is. You now need to use a middleware function with 4 params. function (err, req, res, next) { //do stuff with err }