# How to specify HTTP error code using Express.js?

Tags: node.js, express, http-status-codes

I have tried:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var e = new Error('error message');
    e.status = 400;
    next(e);
});
```

and:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.statusCode = 400;
    var e = new Error('error message');
    next(e);
});
```

but always an error code of 500 is announced.

Comment: My answer to a related question could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170857/can-i-reuse-the-express-js-error-view/10556093#10556093

Comment: Could you please update the accepted response?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to programmatically send a 404 response with Express/Node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393275/how-to-programmatically-send-a-404-response-with-express-node)

Answer (score 425, accepted):

Per the Express (Version 4+) docs, you can use:

```
res.status(400);
res.send('None shall pass');
```

http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.status

<=3.8

```
res.statusCode = 401;
res.send('None shall pass');
```

Comment: +1 for using the latest version of the API.

If you want to send more down the wire, just chain:
`res.status(400).json({ error: 'message' })`

Comment: What about if I don't have a response variable? In a mongoose validation I have to rise an error `done(new Error('My error text'))`

Comment: @Mikel if you don't have a response variable, then you can't sent a response.

Comment: This is all deprecated now, you should use `res.sendStatus(401);`.

Comment: This response would be a lot more complete if it ended with `res.send('Then you shall die')`.

Comment: @Cipi Do you have a source for that? The documentation doesn't indicate `.status()` is deprecated. `.sendStatus()` is just a shorthand for `.status(code).send(codeName)` where the `codeName` is the standard HTTP response text for the given `code`.

Comment: @JamesCoyle My comment was related for a relevant version of Express for year 2017.

Comment: I was surprised that `res.status(400).json(new Error('message'))` did not work.  The result was an empty JSON object `{}`.  Instead, use TyMayn's comment of `res.status(400).json({ error: 'message' })`

Answer (score 120):

A simple one liner;

```
res.status(404).send("Oh uh, something went wrong");
```

Answer (score 46):

I'd like to centralize the creation of the error response in this way:

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res){
  throw {status: 500, message: 'detailed message'};
});

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500).json({status: err.status, message: err.message})
});
```

So I have always the same error output format.

PS: of course you could create an object to [extend the standard error](https://gist.github.com/justmoon/15511f92e5216fa2624b) like this:

```
const AppError = require('./lib/app-error');
app.get('/test', function(req, res){
  throw new AppError('Detail Message', 500)
});
```

---

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function AppError(message, httpStatus) {
  Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
  this.name = this.constructor.name;
  this.message = message;
  this.status = httpStatus;
};

require('util').inherits(module.exports, Error);
```

Comment: great solution but this gives me UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning error. How to make sure the errors are handled in our error middleware

Comment: async/await is not supported out of the box by express, try this https://github.com/fastify/fastify

Comment: `throw` works only if the route is synchronous. If it's an async route, you have to manually call `next()`. I suppose (but haven't tried) you could just pass the same object you show in `throw` but to `next()`.

Answer (score 21):

In express 4.0 they got it right :)

```
res.sendStatus(statusCode)
// Sets the response HTTP status code to statusCode and send its string representation as the response body.

res.sendStatus(200); // equivalent to res.status(200).send('OK')
res.sendStatus(403); // equivalent to res.status(403).send('Forbidden')
res.sendStatus(404); // equivalent to res.status(404).send('Not Found')
res.sendStatus(500); // equivalent to res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error')

//If an unsupported status code is specified, the HTTP status is still set to statusCode and the string version of the code is sent as the response body.

res.sendStatus(2000); // equivalent to res.status(2000).send('2000')
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use `res.send('OMG :(', 404);` just `res.send(404);`

Comment: But I want the error code to be sent to eventHandler middleware, so express's custom error page be displayed.

Comment: For anyone reading this in 2016: As per Express 4.x, `res.send(404)` is deprecated. It's now `res.sendStatus(404)`.  http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendStatus

Answer (score 13):

From what I saw in Express 4.0 this works for me. This is example of authentication required middleware.

```
function apiDemandLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

    // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on
    console.log('isAuth', req.isAuthenticated(), req.user);
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    // If not return 401 response which means unauthroized.
    var err = new Error();
    err.status = 401;
    next(err);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

The version of the errorHandler middleware bundled with some (perhaps older?) versions of express seems to have the status code hardcoded. The version documented here: http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/errorHandler.html on the other hand lets you do what you are trying to do. So, perhaps trying upgrading to the latest version of express/connect.

Answer (score 11):

I tried

```
res.status(400);
res.send('message');
```

..but it was giving me **error**:

> (node:208) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Can't set headers
>   after they  are sent.

This work for me

```
res.status(400).send(yourMessage);
```

Answer (score 9):

Old question, but still coming up on Google. In the current version of Express (3.4.0), you can alter res.statusCode before calling next(err):

```
res.statusCode = 404;
next(new Error('File not found'));
```

Comment: What is does next do?

Comment: `next` is calling next handler which in express.js usually are trying to render error pages.

Answer (score 8):

Express deprecated `res.send(body, status)`.

Use `res.status(status).send(body)` or `res.sendStatus(status)` instead

Comment: Thanks. Wokring with warning of middlewares.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send the status code without its string representation you can do:

```js
res.status(200).send();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend handling the sending of http error codes by using the [Boom](https://github.com/hapijs/boom) package.

Answer (score 0):

Async way:

```
  myNodeJs.processAsync(pays)
        .then((result) => {
            myLog.logger.info('API 200 OK');
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.json(result);
            myLog.logger.response(result);
        })
        .fail((error) => {
            if (error instanceof myTypes.types.MyError) {
                log.logger.info(`My Custom Error:${error.toString()}`);
                res.statusCode = 400;
                res.json(error);
            } else {
                log.logger.error(error);
                res.statusCode = 500;
                // it seems standard errors do not go properly into json by themselves
                res.json({
                    name: error.name,
                    message: error.message
                });
            }
            log.logger.response(error);
        })
        .done();
```