# Express server Error 400 is not returning json message

Tags: node.js, express, iis, axios, http-status-codes

I am submitting a form and if the form id already exists in the database, I am returning status 400 with a message saying that the form exists.

```
res.status(400).send({
   status: 400,
   message: "Form exists"
})
```

When I read the response sent back from my express server, I am getting `Bad request` message instead of the custom message object that I am returning. If I replace `res.status(400)` with `res.status(200)`, I am getting the expected custom message object.

Weird enough, I can get the custom message object when making the server call in development environment. I get `Bad Request` message from my production server and I don't know why the response is different when the environment is different. I am hosting this server on IIS Manager v10

So my question is should I use status code of 200 instead of 400 in this scenario? Is there a way to return a custom message from status 400? Based on my understanding, I should use 4xx status code if there is a client input errors eg there is already an existing ID or invalid inputs.

Edit: This is my code from my React app.

```
axiosInstance
        .post("/form/some-endpoint", formData)
        .then(function () {
          navigate(ROUTE_SUCCESS_PAGE);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
          console.log(error);
          alert(error.response !== undefined ? error.response.data.message : error.message);
        });
```

This is the actual screenshot of the response from prod server (I console log it)

[image]

[image]

But in development environment, I am getting the response that I wanted.
[image]

[image]

Postman response from Prod server:
[image]

Comment: I think the way you are approaching this is correct. More accurately, I think you could return a 409 (Conflict) instead for this case. But I think we need more details on your issue to help you out. How are you sending your requests / reading your responses? Can you show a screenshot of the "Bad Request" output you see?

Comment: as @JaxonCrosmas stated your approach is the right one but in a situation where you want to continue with `response of 2xx`, you can justify it by saying that the data was received and acted on so response `200` is also accepted here but send a message of fail

Comment: @JaxonCrosmas I have added some information that might be useful for us to debug.

Comment: I see you are logging the actual Axios response object to the console (in this case `AxiosError`). The "Bad Request" text in `AxiosError.response.statusText` is not the text returned by your application, it's a description of the `400` status. The data you are looking for is in `AxiosError.response.data`. This field contains the JSON object you returned from your application.

Comment: IISNode or HttpPlatformHandler?

Comment: @LexLi IISNode for the express server

Comment: @JaxonCrosmas The axios error from prod server does not contain the message that I am looking for, if you look closely at the first image: `response: {data: "Bad Request"}` but at the third image: `response:data:{status: 400, message: "RO/Invoice ...}`

I tried making the api call from Postman and I am getting "Bad Request" in the response body. I will attach the screenshot. I suspect something is not working on the server side or the IIS Manager.

Comment: https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/291 With all keywords plus iisnode, a search engine can easily lead you to.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks, I had a feeling that IIS Manager/Node could be the culprit and you had the same suspicious but I am not experienced enough with IIS. I managed to resolve it by adding `<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />` to my web.config. It seems like I need to bypass the IIS http error handler and that did the trick. 

This is the solution to my problem.

Comment: Then you can post and accept your own answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
</system.webServer>
```

Adding the `<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />` to the server's web.config file on IIS Manager resolved my issue. Based on my understanding, bypassing the http error handler  and not letting IIS to send its response is the solution that I need.

Answer (score 0):

> should I use status code of 200 instead of 400 in this scenario

TLDR: It depends on the usage.

If your intent is to **U**pdate a form, like using a `PUT` request, you should require an `id` and if that `id` does not exist, return [`404`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404).

If you are looking to **C**reate a new form, like using a `POST` request, with an `id` or other meta data and one already exists matching the `id` or meta data (e.g. `groupId`), then [`400`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) is fine but it could be better to use [`409`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/409) stating that there is a conflict with the existing state, that being a preexisting form id or meta data. Though you don't often pass an `id` to a `POST` create request.

The full [list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) of codes is a great place to start, but sometimes it helps to see how certain codes are used in production APIs. A good place to look is the [GitHub API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest) which shows the possible status codes for each endpoint along with a description. Take the [Pulls API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/pulls) for example, just searching for `40` on the page gives you a lot of insight about when certain codes are used.

Comparing these statuses with your example, if you look at the [PUT `/repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls/{pull_number}/merge`](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/pulls#merge-a-pull-request) route, they use [`409`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/409) whenever the state is not matching as they describe...

> Conflict if sha was provided and pull request head did not match

This seems similar in nature to the `POST` request described above.

At the end of the day the crucial part is to get in the correct grouping (i.e `2xx`, `4xx`, etc.) after that it's more about being consistent across your API than matching the codes to exact best option. Also everyone is different and some may choose different codes for the same use case.

---

As far as changing the response itself on `400` status, you should be able to achieve this by setting `statusMessage` directly and then call [`res.end`](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.end).

```js
function(req, res) {
  res.statusMessage = "Form exists";
  res.status(400).end();
}
```

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36507614/6943587