# Rendering view in Node/Express always causes error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've configured my nodejs/express application as follows;

```
app.set('views', __dirname + './views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Then I added a route like so

```
app.get('/page/MyPage', function(req, res) {

    // res.statusCode = 200; // Setting the status code here has no effect on the error.
    res.render('MyPage', { Data: "Stuff" });

});
```

However, whenever I request the page `http://localhost:8000/page/MyPage` node crashes out with `TypeError: Cannot call method 'toString' of undefined`, breaking in the `http.js` class.

The exact line:

```
 var statusLine = 'HTTP/1.1 ' + statusCode.toString() + ' ' +
               reasonPhrase + CRLF; // Aprox line 1180, in ServerResponse.prototype.writeHead = function(statusCode) function.
```

I've tried adding extensions to the 'MyPage' within render, and also tried other view engines. All of which yield the same result.

The view does exist in the /views directory.

**Does anybody have any suggestions?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to specify HTTP error code in express.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563644/how-to-specify-http-error-code-in-express-js)

Comment: @OrangeDog, Not a duplicate, that is about attempting to set the http status code, this is about node/express crashing when attempting to render a view.

Comment: Either you're setting it wrongly, your installation is broken, or there's something you've not told us.

Comment: I wish I knew what else to tell, the node/express installation seems fine because I am serving a whole restful api with it, just got a new requirement through for html pages to be rendered.

Comment: A minimal working example that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

After stepping through an awful lot of javascript I have identified the issue. It appears that although the express documentation (http://expressjs.com/guide.html) suggests this is done automatically, I needed to set the view engine manually.

In this instance I also am using the **vash** view engine.

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'vash');
app.engine('.vash', require('vash').renderFile);
```

This allows my views to be rendered as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`app.set('views', __dirname + './views');` should probably be `app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');`

Comment: Unfortunately that causes the same result.