# How to create 503 error in s3fs fuse

Tags: http, http-status-code-503, s3fs

I am trying to replicate a scenario where s3fs command error out with  return code `503` for the request made. How can I recreate this scenario

Answer (score 0):

I created a `node.js` application  which will return `503` status code.

[How to specify HTTP error code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563644/how-to-specify-http-error-code)

Now I use the endpoint of node js application in s3fs command I get the desired result.