# node.js - How are Status Codes Added to Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this code

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const homepage = `${__dirname}/views/index.html`;
const errpage = `${__dirname}/views/404.html`;
const maincss = `${__dirname}/views/Assets/css/main.css`;
const mainjs = `${__dirname}/views/Assets/js/script.js`;
const skull = `${__dirname}/craneo.OBJ`

//pages
app.get("/skull.obj", (req, res) => res.sendfile(skull))
app.get("/", (req, res) => res.sendFile(homepage));
app.get("/style.css", (req, res) => res.sendFile(maincss))
app.get("/script.js", (req, res) => res.sendFile(mainjs))
app.get("*", (req, res) => res.sendFile(errpage)).code(404);

app.listen("80", () => {
    console.log('server started');
});
```

in line 15  i appended `app.get("*", (req, res) => res.sendFile(errpage))` with .code(404); i tested this and inspect element said this gave me a code 200 i am not sure what is the problem i followed the instrutions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23394294/15845993) and i am not sure what the problem with this code is and i new to express

Comment: Where exactly do you see `code(404)` in the linked answer? Programming by guessing doesn't work well. You can't randomly throw words into your code and expect it to work. It's important that the method is called `status` and is called on the `res` object before `sendFile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should use `res.status(xxx)` instead of `res.code(xxx)` like so:

```
app.get("*", (req, res) => res.status(400).sendFile(errpage));
```