# NodeJs ExpressJS Error Handling Trouble

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am having trouble with express Error handling. Here is my configuration for the server.

```
    server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    server.use(server.router);
    server.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
    server.use(express.bodyParser());
```

Then I try adding this line of code

```
server.error(function(err, req, res, next){
if (err instanceof NotFound) {
    res.render('404.jade');
} else {
    next(err);
}
});
```

Then in my console, I get this message,

**Object function app(req, res){ app.handle(req, res); } has no method 'error'**

what am I doing wrong? I cant get error handling to work.

Comment: Check my answer to a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170857/can-i-reuse-the-express-js-error-view/10556093#10556093

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of express are you using?

Because there is a new *3.x* version (**still in alpha stage**) out that changed quite [a lot of stuff](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/History.md), and things such as the error handling is changed

Check out the [migration guide from 2.x to 3.x](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x)

The page is a work in progress, consider moving back to *2.x* or waiting for a better *3.x* documentation and migration guide

Comment: Yeah it seems that 3.X was installed. Will Check a way to down grade. Will See if npm has functions for this. Thanks!

Comment: Just do: npm install express@2.5.9

Comment: Yeah, but it seems that 2.59 is not compatible with my version of node.  I have node v0.7.2-pre installed. I was wondering if there was a way to downgrade this. Thanks Man.

Comment: no fix this in stalled a package called n, which handles binaries of node. Cool

Comment: yep, I know, I answered your other question ;)